# CSS background image does not show up in IE 7 and 8

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer, background

URL is http://site1.ewart.library.ubc.ca/node/255

The carousel on the page has a background image

```
#webcastingslideshow {
    background: url("images/webcasting/carousel_background.png") no-repeat scroll left   top transparent;
}
```

It works on FF (and Chrome) but not with IE 7 and 8. Instead, the background image does not show up in IE at all (just a white background).

I guess it might be some overlay of DIVs but I am not sure.

Any advice?

Thank you,

Comment: FYI: the background image was carousel_background.gif. I created a PNG and imported that GIF to generate a PNG, hoping that a PNG will work. But it doesn;t.

Comment: pngs dont actually work out of the box in ie. you'll need some hacks for that

Comment: @corroded: They work in IE7 and above. They still display in IE6, just without any transparency.

Comment: IE6 transparency yes, png support is fine in IE7+

Comment: Hi folks, could you please clarify? What hacks shall is needed? I tested above URL in my Ie 7 and 8 and it does not work. It works on your IE?

Comment: I had a similar issue, the images specified in background didn't show up on IE 7 and 8. After running the images through smushit it suddenly worked. I suspect that the designer used cmyk color format that isn't supported in those versions of IE.

Answer (score 3):

Add `overflow: hidden` to `#webcastingslideshow`.